# I'm new to flutter and I'm facing a connection issue when I run my app

Tags: flutter

This is the error message  get whenever I run the emulator : E/flutter (30150): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Connection timed out, host: 10.0.2.2, port: 3306

Comment: are you connecting mysql

Comment: here is the answer to your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60155822/i-flutter-30720-socketexception-os-error-connection-timed-out-errno-110